# I can't seem to change access in the command line for a file

Tags: git, command-line, terminal, permissions, git-lfs

I am currently trying to install git lfs (I am using a git hub repository to make a portfolio and am uploading some large files). I followed the instructions on the download website (https://help.github.com/articles/installing-git-large-file-storage/), but when I try to run the install.sh file in terminal I get this:

rm: /usr/local/bin/git-lfs: Permission denied

I tried to change the permission of the file using this:

chmod a+rwx /usr/local/bin/git-lfs

When I tried to run install.sh again I got the same permission denied prompt. I am still very new to coding in general so I don't really know what I am doing with a lot of command line permission stuff, so I might be missing something very obvious. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to run `sudo ./install.sh`

Running `sudo` will run the install script as root, which will give the installer the appropriate permissions to complete those operations.

Here is a complete guide to installing git-lfs:

[Download Latest LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -zxvf git-lfs-*
cd git-lfs-*
sudo ./install.sh
git lfs install
```

Comment: Im getting the error tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'git-lfs-linux-*'. The zip file downloaded as git-lfs-darwin-amd64-1.4.1 (5).tar.gz and I'm working on a Mac if that makes any difference?

Comment: That definitely makes a difference. `tar -zxvf git-lfs-darwin*` instead of the other tar.

Comment: I have changed the answer to work for mac as well. Enjoy.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!